# Gooble Cloud KMS: code freezes on calling kms client

Tags: google-cloud-kms

I want to encrypt and decrypt son values by using `google cloud kms` and I am using this code as example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/kms/src/main/java/com/example/CryptFile.java

```
try (KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create()) {

  // The resource name of the cryptoKey
  String resourceName = CryptoKeyName.format(projectId, locationId, keyRingId, cryptoKeyId);

  // Encrypt the plaintext with Cloud KMS.
  EncryptResponse response = client.encrypt(resourceName, ByteString.copyFrom(plaintext));

  // Extract the ciphertext from the response.
  return response.getCiphertext().toByteArray();
}
```

When the code executes the line `client.encrypt(resourceName, ByteString.copyFrom(plaintext));` it freezes and I do not get any response.

If I use `gcloud` command to encrypt/decrypt it works.

I run my application on `App Engine` standard (runtime java8) and the dependency I am using is

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-kms</artifactId>
        <version>1.29.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I made some changes in my code to get credentials:

```
    AppIdentityService appIdentityService = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
    GoogleCredentials credentials = AppEngineCredentials.newBuilder().setScopes(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudkms")).
            setAppIdentityService(appIdentityService).build();

    FixedCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials);
    KeyManagementServiceSettings kmsSettings = KeyManagementServiceSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();

    try (KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create(kmsSettings)) {
```

But I always get "UNAUTHENTICATED: Failed computing credential metadata".

Any help?
Please let me know if I'm missing something here.

Regards

Comment: What version of the KMS client library are you using? Is this app engine standard or flex? What version of Java?

Comment: I edited the post to add Appengine standard - runtime8 and google-cloud-kms (1.29.0)

Comment: And you’ve given the app engine service account the right permissions? https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/accessing-the-api

Comment: yes, all permissions are granted

Answer (score 0):

Same thing, running the code from example hags on the call to encrypt

Json auth file is set to the environment
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="../my.json"

User is granted the correct permission as per documentation
Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter

Verified in debugger all 4 parameters are correct:
projectId, locationId, keyRingId, cryptoKeyId

This code hangs

```
try (KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create()) {

            final String resourceName = CryptoKeyName.format(projectId, locationId, keyRingId, cryptoKeyId);

            // Always Hangs here!!!!
            final EncryptResponse response = client.encrypt(resourceName, ByteString.copyFromUtf8(data));

            return response.getCiphertext().toString();
        }
```

Comment: Did you find out the reason for this issue